# Variable within bool function won't change

Tags: c#, function, return, boolean

I have this code:

```
private bool GetSource(string toSearchFor)
{
    bool test = false;
    func3("2000");
    browser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
    {
        var html = taskHtml.Result;
        //printLine(html.ToString());
        if(html.ToString().Contains(toSearchFor))
        {
            test = true;
            printLine("found TOSEARCHFOR:" + toSearchFor + " and test variable is: " + test);
        }
        else
        {
            test = false;
        }
    });

    if(test == false)
    {
        printLine("false in test area-----------------------------");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        printLine("true in test area-----------------------------");
        return true;
    }

}
```

So I need to return true or false for the bool. When I put `return false;` or `return true;` in the first if/else statement, I get an error that not all paths return true. If I run this code, `printLine("found TOSEARCHFOR:" + toSearchFor + " and test variable is: " + test);` prints `test` variable as true, but this returns false. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: becuase of `GetSourceAsync`

Comment: As it says in the name `browser.GetSourceAsync()` is Asynchronous, which means it doesn't execute right away. So the rest of the code will execute before your anonymous functions runs, leading it to return `false` before the value of `test` is changed.

Comment: @ninja how can I wait for GetSourceAsync to finish

Comment: In addition, you need to change how this function works or how does the caller calls it.

Comment: Try using ```await GetSourceAsync()```